# Will current (2021) Campagnolo brakes have sufficient clearance for 28c tyres and mudguards?

Tags: rim-brake, campagnolo

I believe that current Campagnolo brakes don't have a quick-release mechanism on the brakes themselves, which means that unless they are paired with Campagnolo levers, it could be awkward to remove a wheel with an inflated 28c.

But I think that otherwise the dual-pivot Campagnolo callipers will clear a mudguard and 28c tyre (assuming the right frame) - is that correct?

Comment: Which exact model? A quick search suggests there's more than one and without knowing that your question would take more effort to answer

Comment: The Record and Super Record brakes are advertised as 28mm compatible.

Comment: @ChrisH As far as I understand, all the current Campagnolo rim brakes share the same basic geometry, and are only differentiated in other aspects of their design. So the same answer would apply to them all.

Comment: Campy sidepulls never have QRs and so always have this gotcha when paired with non-Ergo levers.